# Wanting to put open railing on stairs but framers seem to have made the banister load bearing. Is this going to be hard to change?

Tags: framing, stairs, load-bearing

Our home is in framing phase but we didn’t get to choose finishes. They are framing it for an enclosed wall staircase but I want to change it to railing as soon as I move I.  However, the framing looks very poor on the stairs and looks possibly load bearing. Is this going to be an issue? Should I talk to the builder?
[image]

Comment: Talking to the builder seems to be the most logical approach. He's the one who has all the plans, knows where all the loads transfer and knows exactly what it will take to adjust framing at this stage to do what you want. That said, the portion of wall closest to camera with the 8 lowest stairs (except the 1 behind the post) is _not_ load bearing. The studs are 24"oc at the bottom and 16"oc at the top and there's no load bearing between them. That's... weird.

Comment: @FreeMan looks like a temporary handrail

Comment: OP says, "framing it for an enclosed wall staircase", @jsotola, So I'd _presume_ that it's supposed to be fully walled in, however, it isn't currently fully enclosed as framed.

Comment: maybe it is framed be a pony wall

Comment: I'm confused on several points in the question: **A)** Why you "didn't get to choose finishes" and what that has to do with framing, **B)** What does "change it to railing" actually mean? After all, a stairway is required by code to have a hand rail of some sort. **C)** the floor _trusses_ are absolutely load bearing, which is why the two on this side of the stairway have 3 studs under each end. Since the floor truss is supported by those columns, what's between them only has to keep people from falling from the stairs.

Comment: @SarahChontos your question makes no sense ... why would you let the builder finish a wall only so that you can tear it down after it is completed? ... ask the builder to make changes before any drywall is placed

Comment: Second @jsotola comment. Much easier and simpler to have it done now, than wait to remove all that work and redo it.  Right now 5 minutes and a couple wacks with a hammer and they can do it the way you want.  Talk.